# Your key with fingerprint (...) is not authorized to access <yourapp>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have two heroku accounts with two seperate applications. I am new at this but I think that the key is stuck to one account and isn't allowing me to open another. What do I do, how can I add the other account?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/272465/using-multiple-ssh-public-keys

Comment: i am a new user, and i couldn't understand that link

Comment: You'll need to use multiple keys for it to work (one for each account), the link shows how to set a separate key up for each hostname you connect to. Not the easiest though, so you may just want to use two different local computer accounts for pushing the two applications, that'll make it simple since they don't share keys at all.

Comment: Or you might want to look at this. http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Steps to manage multiple Heroku accounts

Install the plugin from the following URL on your machine

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts

In case you run into the problem of finger print authorization issue then follow the below steps

We had similar problem today and resolved it with the following solution

1. First add account using following command

   > heroku accounts:add account_name --auto

   This command would generate separate public key which would be associated with this account so that it does not conflicts with other accounts.
2. Next step is to create the application for the account using following command

   > heroku create app_name --account account_name
3. Final step is to push the application in the Heroku which is the area where you will experience the fingerprint issue.

   Open the config file in your .ssh folder wherein you will find following entry for your added account.

   > Host heroku.account_name
   >
   > > HostName heroku.com
   > >
   > > IdentityFile /home/icicle/.ssh/identity.heroku.account_name
   > >
   > > IdentitiesOnly yes

   Remove the existing Heroku repository remote and add the new using the following command

   Removing Heroku respository

   > git remote rm heroku

   Add new Heroku respository

   > git remote add heroku git@heroku.account_name:app_name.git

   Here heroku.account_name is the one which is added as Host in your ssh config file.

   Now try to push your application and it works.

Comment: It does not worked for me :/ I was first using one heroku account now I have two one office and one personal personal is not working

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting an error while following Icicle's instructions:

```
'accounts:add' is not a heroku command.
```

So, building on Icicle's answer, you need to install the following plugin before running the commands:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts

Comment: Thanks for your input. Here the assumption was that the user has already installed the plugin. Anyway I have added the step in the above post.